# i want to count words but it is not counting the word once it is appeared in the sentence

Tags: c, string, floating-point, integer, cs50

i want it to count words but it is not counting if the word again appears in the sentence

```
#include <stdio.h> #include <ctype.h> #include <cs50.h> #include <string.h> #include <math.h>

int main(void){ int letters=0; int words=0; int sentences=0; float L; int S; int W; float z; float 

x;

string para =get_string("Text:");

for(int i=0;i<strlen(para);i++){

if((para[i]>='a' || para[i]<='z') && (para[i]>='A' || para[i]<='Z')

&& (para[i]!=' ') && (para[i]!=',') && (para[i]!='-') && (para[i]!='!')

&& (para[i]!='?') && (para[i]!='.') && (para[i]!=';') && (para[i]!=''')){

 L=letters++;

}

if((para[i]==' ') && (para[i]!='.')) { W= words++; }

if((para[i]=='.') || (para[i]=='!') || (para[i]=='?')){ S= sentences++; }

}

L=(float) letters/words * 100; S=(float) sentences/words * 100; //printf("%f\n",z); 

//printf("%f\n",x);

int index=round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8); 

if((index==1) || (index==2) || (index==3) || (index==4) || (index==5) || (index==6) || (index==7) 

|| (index==8) || (index==9) || (index==10) || (index==11) || (index==12) || (index==13) || 

(index==14) || (index==15))

{

 printf("Grade %i\n",index); 

}

 //printf("letters:%i\n",letters); //printf("words:%i\n",words); 

//printf("sentences:%i\n",sentences); 

if(index>=16)

{

 printf("Grade 16+\n");

 } 

else if(index<1)

{ 

printf("Before Grade 1\n"); }

}
```

here is the output

```
Text: would you rather be you.
Grade 5
letters:19
words:4
sentences:1
```

Comment: Could you format the code properly first? I would do it myself, but I'm too lazy.

Comment: Your logic seems unnecessarily complicated. For example, to test if a character is a letter, if you don't want to use built-ins, usually you would do `if((para[i]>='a' && para[i]<='z') || (para[i]>='A' && para[i]<='Z'))` and be done with it.

Comment: what is this? `int index=round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);`. You can also check a range for index .. `if (index >= 1 && index <= 15){ .. }`

Comment: it is the formula

Comment: `para[i]!='''` is a syntax error, you need to escape the `'` character you're looking for: `para[i]!='\''`

Comment: After fixing that, ripping out the cs50 stuff, and adding `printf`s for the variables you want to see, looks like it works as intended to me, including for a sentence with repeating words: https://godbolt.org/z/Wo91G75qP

Comment: Your if statement has to many “||”, it works, but there’s a much more easier way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, follow the instruction in the comment section for beautifying your code so that other can easily understand what is implemented there.

Secondly, The duplicity of words is not a problem here. In your code, you are counting the spaces for the word counting. Usually, we can say that two words are separated by one space, so there is always an extra word eg:

```
I am counting the spaces and the words.
```

here the words = 8 & spaces =7

But if I put extra spaces in the sentence, your code also counts the space as a word.  eg:

```
I am counting the spaces    and the words.
```

here the words = 8 & spaces = 10

So the logic has to change. I am sharing some ideas about this:

```
 1. Check the next letter after getting spaces.
 2. If letter then count word.
 3. If get '.' then count another word.
 4. Skip the signs except '.'.
```

Hopefully, you will get the right number of words.

Answer (score 0):

`if((para[i]==' ') && (para[i]!='.')) { W= words++; }` is amiss.

If `para[i]==' '` is true, `para[i]!='.'` is also true and not needed.

If `para[i]==' '` is false, `para[i]!='.'` is irrelevant and not needed.

So code is the same as:

```
if(para[i] == ' ') W = words++;
```

Note `W` is never used.

---

I suspect OP wants

`if((para[i]==' ') || (para[i]=='.')) { W= words++; }`

---

For me, I would count *words* based on non-letter followed by letter.

```
char previous = '\n';
for (size_t i=0; para[i]; i++) {
  if (!isalpha(previous) && isalpha(para[i])) words++;
  previous = para[i];
}
```

---

Other issues exists too, yet the above addresses OP's concern.